# How do I reset systemd-logind vram without restarting or logging out

Tags: systemd, ram, logind

Sometimes on various machines in various distros with various cpu/gpu architectures, users will find systemd-logind to accumulate a large quantity of ram/vram if the machine has not been restarted for several hours. And, such a user will want to remove that ram/vram from the logind process without restarting their machine.

I would like to know how to target this systemd-logind process and reset its ram to the state it is in at restart.

My specific machine is running Manjaro-stable/Gnome , Ryzen 7 Lenovo with integrated graphics.  The screenshot below shows my logind process and the VRAM that I will want to refresh/flush/clear.  This current level 218564 KiB seems fine to me but when it grows, I will want to clear it back to this level again.

```
sudo umr -t
```

[image]

I would also like to note that `systemctl restart systemd-logind` causes my machine to logout and then I will need to force reboot in order to get back in.  So, for me at least,  `systemctl restart systemd-logind` is not the answer.